# reading input and calling the array index

Tags: java

I'll try explaining my problem without listing code since it is an assignment and I don't want any plagiarism occurring, but if needs be then I will post it up.

I'm currently reading entries from a text file, like the following :

> John James 383838 
>   Paul Size  38525 
>   Steve Dog  45455

I have my scanInput class setup to do this. I can call e.g. getNumber() and it will only ever return the most recent one. In this case being 45455.

I am using a counter in my method e.g. `array[count].setNumber`
and then once it's read through the 3 surname, initial and number it goes `count++`;

So I assume it should then go back into the while loop and read the others. I'm a bit confused. No matter which index I call it'll always return the most recent one.

For example

```
object.ScanInput();
System.out.println(object.getEntry()[2].getNumber());
```

will return the same value ( the most recent entry number in the txt file ). So it doesn't matter which index is called, the same value is always returned.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You need to show us your code, so that someone can help (for example the implementation of `getNumber` and any relevant classes).

Comment: http://vvcap.net/db/sXyFuBNoblaNUY6QSJj6.htp I've took a print screen here of my method

Comment: @user3551586 It might be that the array has references to the same object. You can check that by printing default `toString()` of the objects inside array...

Comment: Try `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(object.getEntry()));`

Comment: that will print out all entries. If i want to print out a specific index number. For example line 2 should be array [1] so if i call getNumber index 1, then it should print out the number for the text file line 2 but instead it always prints the most recently added, so the last one

Comment: @user3551586 But, **does** it print all of the entries?

Answer (score 0):

The contents are all separated by a whitespace, so that should be your delimiter. I would scan in an entire line and split it by white spaces.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to venture a guess I would say the same object was added to the array for each index. So all iterations of the loop assign the member variables of that object.

Did you mistakenly do something like this?

```
  Entry[] entries = new Entry[3];
  Entry e = new Entry();

  for (int i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
     entries[i] = e; // All items in the array contain the same Object
  }
```

You could do this instead (Since you said you can't use a list):

```
  Entry[] entries = new Entry[3];

  int count = 0;
  while(inFile.hasNext()) {
     String line = inFile.nextLine();
     lineScanner = new Scanner(line);
     Entry e = new Entry();
     e.setSurname(lineScanner.next());
     e.setInitial(lineScanner.next());
     e.setNumber(lineScanner.next());
     entries[count++] = e;
  }
```

Comment: Can't do the ArrayList idea unfortunately - it'd be much easier, but we're only able to use an Array

Comment: and ye I think you're right about the first problem ^.^ http://vvcap.net/db/EHRVcgm2qCzWD9w3uZc9.htp so you're probably right it's just taking the one value ?

Comment: Well if you step through it is updating the same object multiple times. If you were to reorder the lines in the input file you would get a different result. If it is using the same object you will always get the values of the last entry.

Comment: Based on your screenshot in the comment above the problem is definitely that you are using the same object for all elements of the array.

Comment: Ah ok thanks, that's a good starting point! at least I know where I'm going wrong ;D now to fix it!

Comment: If you feel my answer was correct please flag it as such. Glad I could help.